# Lost SSH Access on AWS EC2 Instance Due to iptables restrictions

Tags: ssh, debian, iptables, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Debian Linux EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services, and I am using iptables to open ports only from specific IP addresses. Unfortunately, all of the allowed IP addresses changed and I now can no longer access the system from anywhere.

Is there a way I can get access to my system again?

Comment: they have Security Groups to do this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop your instance and disassociate the EBS volume from that instance. Mount the existing root volume as a data drive on a new instance. Change the configuration of IPTables, then turn that instance off and disassociate it from the second instance. Reattach it to the first instance, or a new instance, and run.